# Limit Excel file to save only as macro enabled (.xlsm or .xlmt) by using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the code below to limit both save and save as to save file with macros. Code is placed in "ThisWorkbook".

My main goal is to create a template with macros for other to use, but when they open the template the often forget to save it with macros because the default setting is .xlsx format.

The excel template is placed in Sharepoint as read only for all. People when then save a copy in their own folder either on sharepoint or a server.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

' Declare variables.
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileLocation As String

' Check if the Save As command is being used.
If SaveAsUI = True Then

    ' Create a FileDialog object.
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    ' Set the file filter.
    fd.FilterIndex = 2
    fd.Filters.Clear
    fd.Filters.Add "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook", "*.xlsm"
    fd.Filters.Add "Excel Macro-Enabled Template", "*.xltm"

    ' Display the file dialog box.
    If fd.Show = -1 Then
        FileName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Save the workbook or template with macros.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If Right(FileName, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Cancel = True

End If

End Sub
```

But I get this error when saving:
[image]
[image]

Screenshot for last comment:
[image]

Comment: I expect you will find this an uphill struggle. It is likely Macros are disabled by default from Sharepoint and/or network settings for at least some people so they would need to both allow macros and then save as .xlsm. When dealing with groups like this, trying to 'foolproof' the workbook has always seemed like a large loss of time as there are so many ways to bypass any process used. I find the simplest process is usually the easiest so a MsgBox popup might serve just as well.

Comment: So you would create a msg box that pops up before save and saveas that simply reminds people to save with macros?

Comment: I would probably create a BeforeSave function which just checks the extension of the save filename and if it isn't ".xltm" or ".xlsm" cancel the save and popup the reminder.

Comment: can you help me with the code for that?

Comment: `FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)` does not accept filters... You should use `GetSaveAsFilename`. I will place an answer strictly related to this part.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my above comment, `FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)' does not accept filters. So, everything related to filters will raise errors. Please, use the next way, instead:

```
Sub testSaveAsFilename()
 Dim fileSaveName As String, fileName As String

 fileName = left(ThisWorkbook.name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.name, ".") - 1): Stop

 fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fileName, _
                            FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)," & "*.xlsm, Excel Macro-Enabled Template " & _
                            "Workbook (*.xlst), *xlst", Title:="Save AS  MACRO ENABLED:")
 Debug.Print fileSaveName
End Sub
```

I did not implement it in your code, but it should be something extremely simple, I think...

And I would also like to suggest to use only `*.xlsm` as filter. Do you want them keeping the template on their own computer? I think it may be a spring of problems... I mean, if you modify the template and they keep using the saved once. In order to make the code letting you save it as template you can add the second filter conditioned by your user name.

In fact, such a version will look as:

```
Sub testSaveAsFilenameOnlyXlsm()
 Dim fileSaveName As String, fileName As String, filt As String
 
 fileName = left(ThisWorkbook.name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.name, ".") - 1)
 If Application.userName = "your user name" Then
        filt = "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)," & "*.xlsm, Excel Macro-Enabled Template " & _
                "Workbook (*.xlst), *xlst"
 Else
        filt = "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)," & "*.xlsm"
 End If
 
 fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fileName, _
        FileFilter:=filt, Title:="Save AS  MACRO ENABLED:")
                                        
 Debug.Print fileSaveName
End Sub
```

You may encrypt your user name and place it in a variable, to not be so clear for all not skilled (in VBA) users...

Re **Edited**:

The above code implemented in your code event:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim fileSaveName As String, FileName As String, filt As String, posDot As Long
 Const yourUserName As String = "your real user name" 'addapt it, please
 
 ' Check if the Save As command is being used.
 If SaveAsUI = True Then
        posDot = InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") 'check if a dot exists in the name (to separate extension)
        If posDot > 0 Then
            FileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
        Else
            FileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
        End If
        If Application.UserName = "Fane Branesti" Then 'for your user name to also allow xltm extension:
               filt = "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)," & "*.xlsm, Excel Macro-Enabled Template " & _
                       "Workbook (*.xltm), *xltm"
        Else
               filt = "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)," & "*.xlsm"
        End If
        
        fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=FileName, _
        FileFilter:=filt, Title:="Save AS  MACRO ENABLED:")
        If fileSaveName = "False" Then Cancel = True: Exit Sub

        Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events after SaveAs
            If Right(fileSaveName, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            Else
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'reenable events
        
        Cancel = True 'stop saving in the standard way
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - they should not keep the template on their own locations. I needed it to be able to save the template my self.

Comment: I just tested your code as is. It works fine, but not if I use the save as command...

Comment: @Jesper Kindt Larsen This makes me think that you did not correctly implemented in your code... I will edit the answer and add your code as it should be adapted. Without testing it. If an error, please mention what error on which line.

Comment: @Jesper Kindt Larsen Please, test the code placed after **Edited** and send some feedback.

Comment: I get a runtim error 5 in this line:         FileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)

Comment: (invalid procedure or call argument)

Comment: @Jesper Kindt Larsen When the template is open, **does it have any extension**? Most probably, not... I tested the code on my testing workbook, which has. If so, please use `FileName = ThisWorkbook.name` instead.

Comment: It seems to work, but if I cancel the save it automatically creates a file called false.xltm....

Comment: and when I save it it pops up with a save dialog once more....

Comment: @Jesper Kindt Larsen It cannot do that... If you cancel, this line `If fileSaveName = "" Then Cancel = True: Exit Sub` should not let it save. For the second issue, place a second `Cancel = True` before `End If`. Now I need to close my laptop and leave office...

Comment: @Jesper Kindt Larsen Please, test the updated code. I am at home and I made some tests. When `Cancel` is pressed `fileSaveName` becomes "False" not null string ("") as I thought. Then, I also placed `Cancel = True` after saving, to avoid the second `SaveAs` window...

Comment: It almost works now. SUper fine if I use the browse button in the dialog (opens a popup where it has chosen format with macros) but in the other window it shows the .xlsx format (see screenshot added to end of original post)

Comment: @Jesper Kindt Larsen „The other window” shouldn't appear...  The window title should be "Save AS  MACRO ENABLED:". Do you have `Cancel = True` before the last `Ent If`?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code and just replaced my username and the other line:         FileName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)   with  
        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Name

Comment: @Jesper Kindt Larsen OK. I did not test the code in such an environment and I need to do it. I will see what's happening and adapt it to work as it should. In 5, 6 minutes I will adapt the code.

Comment: @Jesper Kindt Larsen Please, test the adapted code. It should work now. The `SaveAs` event used to be triggered **once more when saved in code**... I also added a sequence checking if a template is opened (by opening from Excel using Open), having `xltm` extension or by double click in its location, not having any extension...